# In Android Ndk programming getting UTF String

Tags: android, string, android-ndk, utf

As you can see, I get jbyte *str form the utf string. Then each character of string has two jbytes else one byte?

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL 

Java_Prompt_getLine(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring prompt) { 

    char buf[128];
    const jbyte *str;
    str = (env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, prompt, NULL);

    if (str == NULL) { 
        return NULL; / OutOfMemoryError already thrown */ 
    }

    printf("%s", str);

    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, prompt, str); 
    /* We assume here that the user does not type more than * 127 characters */ 
    scanf("%s", buf);

    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, buf);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
str = (env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, prompt, NULL);
```

you receive buffer of single byte chars. You may even edit this like here:

```
const char *str = (env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, prompt, NULL);
```

because `GetStringUTFChars()` is declared as returning `const char *`.

Comment: No! The array returned by `GetStringUTFChars` is Unicode characters in a modified UTF-8 encoding. Each character will take one to six bytes. If you want a character set/encoding with one byte per character then use a `String.getBytes` overload or the `Charset` class.